# HTML Data URIs Browser Compatibility

Tags: html, css, data-uri

I was wondering what the browser support is for Data URIs? More specifically what version of IE does this begin to be supported in?

Also is there a difference between using them in a stylesheet as a BG image or in an img tag?

Cheers!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+support+is+for+Data+URIs

Comment: Thanks i know how to Google something, but there are a bunch of different articles out there that contradict each other. I trust the opinions of the SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow caniuse.com, it hasn't failed me yet.

http://caniuse.com/datauri

According to caniuse Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, mobile browsers, and IE8+ support Data URIs.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I haven't seen this site but seem very in depth.